# Bootstrap: data-target collapsing several divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two divs which I want to collapse or expand.

If if click on button A, I want to collapse/expand div A.
If if click on button B, I want to collapse/expand div B.

This is my code:

```
<!-- I define data-target=A -->
<div>
    <div data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#A">
    <strong>More...</strong>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- I define data-target=B -->
<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#B">Details</button>


<!-- I define div A -->
<div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="A" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-{{ feature.name }}">
    <div><strong>Long description: ...</strong></div>
</div>

<!-- I define div B -->
<div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="B" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-{{ feature.name }}">
    Blablabla...
</div>
```

"A" works fine. But when I want to collapse/expand "B", it affects both A and B at the same time.

Does anybody what is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You're just missing a `"` here: `id=B"`.

Try this:

```
<div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="B" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-{{ feature.name }}">
    Blablabla...
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I misstyped it when pasting my code here. I do have both `"` simbols.

Comment: Seems to work with the exact code you have posted. Is there something else that might have something to do with this? Demo of your code here: http://www.bootply.com/hJJkGpWB2h

Comment: Thanks Phil. Well, as you demontrated there must be something interfering in my code. But it's long and complex, mixed with Django templates and I can't find it

Answer (score 0):

Make This type your code firstly make for id 'A' and after 'B' your problem will resolved.

```html
<div class="row">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#A">Simple collapsible</button>
  <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="A" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-A">
    <div><strong>Long description: ...</strong></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#B">Simple </button>
 <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="B" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="heading-B">
 <div><strong>Long description: ...</strong></div>
</div>
```